# transferring arraylist from one class to another

Tags: java, class, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to move the data from the stations `ArrayList` in the `fileReader` class into the another ArrayList in the `CTAStops` class. Whenever I test this i get a null pointer exception. What would be the correct way to transfer the data over?

Any help at all would really be appreciated! :)

```
public class FileReader {
    public static ArrayList<CTAStops> stations = new ArrayList<CTAStops>();

    public FileReader(){
        String csvFile = "CTAStops (2).csv";
        File file = new File(csvFile);

        try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

            inputStream.nextLine();
            inputStream.nextLine();

            while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = inputStream.nextLine();
                String var[] = data.split(",");

                stations.add(new CTAStops(var[0],Double.parseDouble(var[1]), 
                                                 Double.parseDouble(var[2]), 
                                                 var[3],Boolean.parseBoolean(var[4]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[5]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[6]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[7]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[8]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[9]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[10]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[11]), 
                                                 Integer.parseInt(var[12])));
            }
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<CTAStops> getList() {
        return stations;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CTAStops extends GeoLocation {

private String StationName; //instance variables that define a ctaStop
private double Latitude;
private double Longitude;
private String Location;
private boolean WheelChair;
private int RedLine;
private int GreenLine;
private int BlueLine;
private int BrownLine;
private int PurpleLine;
private int PinkLine;
private int OrangeLine;
private int YellowLine;

public static ArrayList<CTAStops> stations = new ArrayList<CTAStops>();

static FileReader read = new FileReader();




public CTAStops(){//default constructor


    StationName = "";
    Latitude = 0;
    Longitude = 0;
    Location = "elevated";
    WheelChair = true;
    RedLine = 0;
    GreenLine = 0;
    BlueLine = 0;
    BrownLine = 0;
    PurpleLine = 0;
    PinkLine = 0;
    OrangeLine = 0;
    YellowLine = 0;
    stations = FileReader.getList();
}
public CTAStops(String StationName, double Latitude, double Longitude, String Location, boolean wheelChair, int RedLine,int GreenLine,int BlueLine, int BrownLine, int PurpleLine, int PinkLine, int OrangeLine, int YellowLine){//nondefault constructor


    this.StationName = StationName;
    this.Latitude = Latitude;
    this.Longitude = Longitude;
    this.Location = Location;
    this.WheelChair = WheelChair;
    this.RedLine = RedLine;
    this.GreenLine = GreenLine;
    this.BlueLine = BlueLine;
    this.BrownLine = BrownLine;
    this.PurpleLine = PurpleLine;
    this.PinkLine = PinkLine;
    this.OrangeLine = OrangeLine;
    this.YellowLine = YellowLine;
}
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: The one with the main method where im testing

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CTAStops.main(CTAStops.java:164)

Comment: The error is in CTAStops

Comment: Wait a minute... why do you have two main methods?

Comment: cause im an idiot

Comment: Well, the issue is that you're calling `stations.get(0)` without creating a `CTAStops` object, so the constructor is never called and `stations` is never initialized. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I do that and the nullpointer goes away but im still getting an arraylist with size zero in CTAStops. I tried it in a test class too. I know for a fact that the file does get read in in FileReader

Comment: Could it have something to do with the getList method?

Comment: Well, your code doesn't even make sense because it has two main methods. Are these two different programs? If so, how are they connected?

Comment: I just threw in a main method for a second to test it thats all

Comment: I feel like the issue is that i can't just return station in the getList() method. I need to clone it or something along those lines

Comment: Rewrite your code with one main method, so we can make sense out of it. Right now everything is a big mess. You're even given parameters to the `CTAStops` constructor in the `FileReader` class even though you don't have a constructor with parameters.

Comment: Ok. There's one main method

Comment: I should really have no main methods in either of these classes. It should only be my application class. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Well, I'm saying this again. `CTAStops` only has the default constructor. There is no constructor with parameters but you're still giving parameters to the constructor. You should be getting a compilation error. Why are you not getting a compilation error? Have you not included the whole code?

Comment: I'll add the rest of it

Comment: do i need to add something to the nondefault constructor in CTAStops?

Comment: Simplest way would be creating a method called `getStations()`  in `FileReader` class which would read your `CSV` file and build an `ArrayList<CTAStops>()` and finally, return the same.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have two main methods in two classes?

I guess CTAStops is your Main class?

What I'd do is have a constructor for FileReader class with filename as parameter and in it have a method returning ArrayList.

Create an instance of FileReader in CTAStops with the input file name(args[0]), then call the method of FileReader and set it equal to any ArrayList.

Also try avoiding FileReader/ FileWriter as class name as it can conflict with the java FileReader and FileWriter classes/constructors.

You should get an idea from this:

```
public class FileProcessor {
private ArrayList<CTAStops> stations = new ArrayList<CTAStops>();
private String filename;

public FileProcessor(String filenameIn) {
    filename = filenameIn;
}

public ArrayList<CTAStops> getStations() throws IOException {
    String csvFile = filename;
    File file = new File(csvFile);

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String var[] = line.split(",");

            stations.add(new CTAStops(var[0], Double.parseDouble(var[1]),
                    Double.parseDouble(var[2]),
                    var[3], Boolean.parseBoolean(var[4]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[5]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[6]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[7]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[8]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[9]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[10]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[11]),
                    Integer.parseInt(var[12])));
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stations;
}

public ArrayList<CTAStops> getList() {
    return stations;
   }
}
```

CTAStops:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CTAStops {
private String StationName; //instance variables that define a     ctaStop
private double Latitude;
private double Longitude;
private String Location;
private boolean WheelChair;
private int RedLine;
private int GreenLine;
private int BlueLine;
private int BrownLine;
private int PurpleLine;
private int PinkLine;
private int OrangeLine;
private int YellowLine;

public static ArrayList<CTAStops> stations = new ArrayList<CTAStops>();

public CTAStops(){//default constructor


    StationName = "";
    Latitude = 0;
    Longitude = 0;
    Location = "elevated";
    WheelChair = true;
    RedLine = 0;
    GreenLine = 0;
    BlueLine = 0;
    BrownLine = 0;
    PurpleLine = 0;
    PinkLine = 0;
    OrangeLine = 0;
    YellowLine = 0;
}
public CTAStops(String StationName, double Latitude, double Longitude, String Location, boolean wheelChair, int RedLine,int GreenLine,int BlueLine, int BrownLine, int PurpleLine, int PinkLine, int OrangeLine, int YellowLine){//nondefault constructor


    this.StationName = StationName;
    this.Latitude = Latitude;
    this.Longitude = Longitude;
    this.Location = Location;
    this.WheelChair = WheelChair;
    this.RedLine = RedLine;
    this.GreenLine = GreenLine;
    this.BlueLine = BlueLine;
    this.BrownLine = BrownLine;
    this.PurpleLine = PurpleLine;
    this.PinkLine = PinkLine;
    this.OrangeLine = OrangeLine;
    this.YellowLine = YellowLine;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileProcessor reader = new FileProcessor("inpp.txt");
    stations = reader.getStations();
    //Testing
    CTAStops a = new CTAStops();
    a=stations.get(0);
    System.out.println(a.StationName +" "+ a.Latitude);


   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that in a bit more detail please? Just a little lost